# Save the selections in JFace Dialog (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, dialog, eclipse-rcp

I have a dialog which consists of multiple checkboxes. when a user click on a button the dialog opens and all the checkboxes are selected by default. the user can uncheck some checkboxes. Second time the user click on the button I want the dialog to be loaded with the previous settings the user did on the first click. Is there any way in which I can load the last entered values of a dialog instead of loading the default settings for the dialog?

My code

The button

```
Button btnSelectChapters = new Button(composite, SWT.NONE);
    btnSelectChapters.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            SelectChaptersDialog chaptersdialog = new SelectChaptersDialog(getShell());
            int result = chaptersdialog.open();
            if (result == 1)
                return;
            else{
                selectedChapters = chaptersdialog.getSelectedChapters();
            }
        }
    });
    btnSelectChapters.setBounds(150, 0, 90, 25);
    btnSelectChapters.setText("Select Chapters");
```

The Dialog

```
  @Override
protected Control createDialogArea(Composite parent) {
    setTitleImage(ResourceManager.getPluginImage("Featuremodel.aspecgeneration", "icons/pdf.png"));
    setTitle("Chapters Selection for Document Generation");
    setMessage("Select chapters you want to include in the document");
    Composite area = (Composite) super.createDialogArea(parent);
    area.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Composite composite_2 = new Composite(area, SWT.NONE);
    composite_2.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true, 1, 1));
    composite_2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

    Composite compositeChapters = new Composite(composite_2, SWT.NONE);
    compositeChapters.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false, 1, 1));
    compositeChapters.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, false));

    Group grpChapters = new Group(compositeChapters, SWT.NONE);
    grpChapters.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, false));
    grpChapters.setText("Chapters");
    grpChapters.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER, true, false, 2, 1));

    btnPandA = new Button(grpChapters, SWT.CHECK);
    btnPandA.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 2, 1));
    btnPandA.setText("Preface/Appendix Chapters");
    btnPandA.setSelection(prefs.get("PA"));
    new Label(compositeChapters, SWT.NONE);
    btnPandA.addSelectionListener(new SelectionListener() {

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            if(btnPandA.getSelection()){
                btnPandAR.setEnabled(true);     
            }
            else{
                btnPandAR.setSelection(false);
                btnPandAR.setEnabled(false);        
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
        }
    });

    btnPandAR = new Button(grpChapters, SWT.CHECK);
    btnPandAR.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 2, 1));
    btnPandAR.setText("Recursive Preface/Appendix Chapters");
    btnPandAR.setEnabled(false);
    btnPandAR.setSelection(true);
    new Label(compositeChapters, SWT.NONE);

    btnCD = new Button(grpChapters, SWT.CHECK);
    btnCD.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 2, 1));
    btnCD.setText("Component Description Chapter");
    btnCD.setSelection(true);
    btnCD.setEnabled(false);
    new Label(compositeChapters, SWT.NONE);

    btnCV = new Button(grpChapters, SWT.CHECK);
    btnCV.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 2, 1));
    btnCV.setText("Context View Chapter");
    btnCV.setSelection(true);
    btnCV.setEnabled(false);
    new Label(compositeChapters, SWT.NONE);

    btnAV = new Button(grpChapters, SWT.CHECK);
    btnAV.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 2, 1));
    btnAV.setText("Architecture View Chapter");
    btnAV.setSelection(true);
    btnAV.setEnabled(false);
    new Label(compositeChapters, SWT.NONE);

    btnIF = new Button(grpChapters, SWT.CHECK);
    btnIF.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 2, 1));
    btnIF.setText("Interface Chapter");
    btnIF.setSelection(true);
    btnIF.setEnabled(false);
    new Label(compositeChapters, SWT.NONE);

    btnDV = new Button(grpChapters, SWT.CHECK);
    btnDV.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 2, 1));
    btnDV.setText("Deployment View Chapter");
    btnDV.setSelection(true);
    new Label(compositeChapters, SWT.NONE);

    btnDNV = new Button(grpChapters, SWT.CHECK);
    btnDNV.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 2, 1));
    btnDNV.setText("Dynamic View Chapter");
    btnDNV.setSelection(true);
    new Label(compositeChapters, SWT.NONE);

    btnFandG = new Button(grpChapters, SWT.CHECK);
    btnFandG.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 2, 1));
    btnFandG.setText("Framework And Guidelines Chapter");
    btnFandG.setSelection(true);
    new Label(compositeChapters, SWT.NONE);

    btnPandD = new Button(grpChapters, SWT.CHECK);
    btnPandD.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 2, 1));
    btnPandD.setText("Patterns And Definitions Chapter");
    btnPandD.setSelection(true);
    new Label(compositeChapters, SWT.NONE);

    btnSubSys = new Button(grpChapters, SWT.CHECK);
    btnSubSys.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.LEFT, SWT.CENTER, false, false, 2, 1));
    btnSubSys.setText("Subsystems Chapter");
    btnSubSys.setSelection(true);
    new Label(compositeChapters, SWT.NONE);

    return area;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: As an aside you need to learn about using [Layouts](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Understanding-Layouts/Understanding-Layouts.htm). `setBounds` will produce bad results if the user has changed their fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `IDialogSettings` for this:

```
IDialogSettings settings = Activator.getDefault().getDialogSettings();

// Access an array of values stored in the settings

String [] valuesArray = settings.getArray("key for value");

// Save array of strings in the settings
settings.put("key for value", valuesArray);
```

`Activator` is your plugin activator. `IDialogSettings` also has methods to access single strings, Integers, Longs, Floats and Doubles. You can also add sub-sections if required.

So, for example, when you create a check box button you can use the saved setting with:

```
IDialogSettings settings = Activator.getDefault().getDialogSettings();

Button checkBox = new Button(parent SWT.CHECK);

checkBox.setSelection(settings.getBoolean("checkbox setting key"));
```

Note the default value if the setting has not been saved is false. If you need the default to be 'true' you can use:

```
boolean selection = true;
if (settings.get("checkbox setting key") != null)
  selection = settings.getBoolean("checkbox setting key");

checkbox.setSelection(selection);
```

To save the selections you need to call the `putBooolean` method. One place to do this would be the `okPressed` method:

```
@Override
protected void okPressed()
{
  IDialogSettings settings = Activator.getDefault().getDialogSettings();

  settings.putBoolean("checkbox setting key", checkbox.getSelection());

  super.okPressed();
}
```

Comment: kindly have a look at my edit. I added the dialog code. Do I need to add anything in my Activator Class? Can you please extend your code as regarding my dialog?

Comment: If your plugin activator is the default created for you by Eclipse it should be OK.